# Cannot import google-play-services_lib because the project name is in use

Tags: android, google-maps

I've done an application which displays a Google map referring this tutorial

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidGoogleMaps/article.html

The application has worked fine and it displayed a Google Map as shown in the tutorial. But now, when I open the project, it shows several errors relating to the import of **com.google** packages. I've already added the `google_play_services_lib`. But now, that is not shown in the application. When I try to import the google_play_services_lib again, this error appears,

> "Cannot import google-play-services_lib because the project name is in
>   use"

What is the problem? Please help me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This generally occurs, if you have a project or folder by the same name existing in your workspace.

In general, You can solve it by changing the name of the existing folder using 'F2' shortcut key. But, since this is a library I recommend you to shift the existing folder "google_play_services_lib" from your workspace directory to somewhere else and then again try and import the "google_play_services_lib" .

Answer (score 1):

this means that `google-playservices.lib` is using by another projects, you can solve it by.

- remove the reference to it from the project which is using it.
- OR close that project using eclipse->right click->close.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this project from your workspace then import from your sdk place.
[http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html#Install]

Answer (score 0):

It seems that when you import google-play-services_lib, Eclipse creates a project by the same name. Even though I deleted manually the google-play-services_lib folder from my workspace folder, I also had to delete the google-play-services_lib project in Eclipse as well. After doing it, I was able to import the lib, and then use it in my project.