# Android - Cannot import google-play-services_lib because the project name is in use

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play-services

I know that there are two post like this one in Stackoverflow ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15742469/android-cant-import-google-play-services) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15870989/cannot-import-google-play-services-lib-because-the-project-name-is-in-use)) but I already tried what is described there without any result and I have the feeling that I'm running out of options.

This screenshot is from one of these two posts, but is exactly what I also see.
[image: problem at importing]

In my case, I was never able to make the googlemaps work and I tried to import and copy the stuff in so many different ways that I guess is what lead to the actual situation. In my last attempt, I was going to try to follow the steps described in [this post](http://upintheweb.blogspot.de/2013/02/android-common-issues-while-setting-up.html), which seems to be the most accurate one, but as I said, now I just can't import the google-play-services_lib because keeps telling me that is in use.
I made sure that I deleted the project from my workspace and any other place where it could be stored by searching for it.

Does anyone have an idea that is not described in the other two posts? Creating a new workspace and importing my project and then the google-play-services_lib could be a solution or the problem is of another nature? Is there a way of obtaining more information about the error shown by Eclipse in order to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure there are better ways to do it, but I ended up [creating a new workspace,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7234656/create-a-new-workspace-in-eclipse) importing my project and then importing the google-play-services_lib.

Answer (score 2):

project name already exist on workspace most of time may be named as mainactivity (or other name) try to rename change existing project name and after try to import it!

e.g following steps

first screen shot shows your same error

[image]

after click select all button shows actual error explains below screen shot:

[image]

note this screenshot error message is `Cannot import MainActivity because the project name is in use` after shows project name rename on existing workspace on your eclipse after try again import it will work perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

google-playservices.lib is in use by another Project.

Check following

- close the project who is using it with right click close
- remove the reference from the project who is using it.

Answer (score 0):

I you don't have the library project in your eclipse works space and you still receive this message, you can just close eclipse, go to you `workspace` folder and manually delete the `google-play-service` library from there. then open eclipse and try to add the project again.